# Trying to prove this relationship. Not sure if this is correct.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I am trying to prove whether or not that:

The triangle inequality holds; that is, for every vectors $x$ and $y$, $$||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||,$$ for the vector function $$||x||  =  \sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i.$$

I have this written currently and was wondering if it was sufficient to say that this inequality does not hold.

\begin{align}
||x+y|| &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i+y_i)^2 \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n (x^2_i + 2x_iy_i + y^2_i) \\ &= \sum\limits_{i=i}^n x^2_i + \sum\limits_{i=i}^n2x_iy_i + \sum\limits_{i=i}^ny^2_i \\ &=||x|| + ||y|| + \sum\limits_{i=i}^n2x_iy_i \\ &\neq ||x|| + ||y||.
\end{align}

I’m a C.S. student so proofs aren’t really my strongsuit.

Comment: You wanted to prove an inequality, how would your conclusion show that the _inequality_ doesn't hold?

Comment: What you need is the fact that $\sum\limits_{i=i}^n2x_iy_i$ can be $>0$ and you have to give  specific example for this.

Comment: I think you should have $\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert =(\sum x_i^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}}$. A standard proof considers $ \lvert \lvert x+y \rvert \rvert^2=(x+y)\cdot (x+y)$ and uses Cauchy Schwarz.

Comment: @HappyDay I am determing whether or not the inequality is true or not.

Comment: @jcneek I believe that is for the Euclidean vector norm. I was given the function above without the square root part

Comment: In that case the inequality is false since for example $(1+1)^2> 1^2 + 1^2$

Comment: Euclidean norm is taken with the rational as @jcneek mentioned.

Comment: Lets $x=y=0$ then equality holds.

Answer (score 2):

This inequality is false, picking up where you left off you know that $$||x+y|| = ||x|| + ||y|| + \sum_{i=1}^n 2x_iy_i$$
For the triangle inequality to be true you would need $\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_iy_i\leq 0$, for all $x_i,y_i$. But this is false, for example if $n=2$, let $x = (1,1)$ and $y = (1,1)$ we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_iy_i = 2(1*1 + 1*1) = 4>0$$
(Notice we have $||x+y|| = 2^2+2^2 = 8>||x||+||y|| = 2+2 = 4$)

Comment: @TedShifrin Which inequality has a wrong sign?

Comment: If $||x||+||y||+\sum 2x_iy_i = ||x+y| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$, then $\sum 2x_iy_i \leq 0$, by subtracting $||x||+||y||$ on both sides.

Comment: Sorry. My brain turned backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be a vector with real scalars $a,b$ then  $$\vert av+bv \vert = \vert(a+b)v \vert=\vert a +b \vert\vert v \vert=(a+b)^2\vert v\vert = \vert a^2v \vert + 2ab \vert v \vert + \vert b^2v \vert$$ and so we require $a = a^2$ and $b=b^2$, and $ab=0$. This gives $a(a-1)=0$ and likewise for $b$ so we see $a=b=0$ $a=1,b=0$ and $a=0,b=1$ are all solutions where equality holds.

Comment: If we have $||x|| = \sum_i x_i^2$, doesn't that mean that $||(a+b)v|| = \sum_i ((a+b)v_i)^2 = (a+b)^2||v||$ and not $(a+b)||v||$?

Comment: @Hagamena you're absolutely correct and I fixed my argument accordingly. Thanks.